# How to find a paper size / printable size and set the header and footer on print?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, printing, underscore.js-templating

This is some what difficult me. My client require to print the data's with header and footer on each page.

There is a chance to use a `A4, A3, A5` and `Landscape` papers. How can i able to set the header and footer on each of the page?

And how can i able to set a data length according to the page? is there a way to create print template?

I am using `underscore-template` in `Backbone`.

Any one suggest me a way please?

Answer (score 0):

For your issue no difference which template engine you use.

For doing something with javascript before HTML Document has been printed you could use:

For Firefox and InternetExplorer - [window.onbeforeprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeprint).

Workaround for other browser - [window.matchMedia('print')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia).

---

The better way for having nice look when user tries to print page is to use CSS's media queries, which will apply particular rules when user want to print the HTML Document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

or add media query to your css file:

```
@media screen {
   body {font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;} // this will apply to printed page
}
```

Comment: I am not find your answer any way to useful to me. Please understand my answer or put me your comments if any thing required to clear from my end. But thanks for your answer

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification. What does it mean - _My client require to **print** the data's with header and footer on each page. There is a chance to use a A4, A3, A5 and Landscape papers_ ? So you need to change a look of your HTML page when user tries to print it. Am I right?

Comment: No, I would like to fill the data's according to the page, what i client selects. (And how can i able to set a data length according to the page? )

Comment: What about paper's size (A4, A3, A5, Landscape)?