# google chrome print preview change paper size

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, size

I'm programing on MVC 5 and I have reports on iframes, I can print the reports in letter size, but i have other reports in Legal Size. How I can change the size of paper?
I have tried some javascript but it doesn't work.

```js
 function PrintFrame() {
            iframe = document.getElementById('frame1');
            iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);

                }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. what happened when you googled for htis? have you done any other research? If so - why were the results unsatisfactory?

Comment: i'm googled so hard, but i dont found anything, i want change the properties of the print preview, i used the CSS but doesnt work

Comment: When I googled "javascript print paper size" I got these two stack overflow in the top two results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545849/possible-to-force-printer-setup-paper-size-in-javascript    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772069/how-to-find-a-paper-size-printable-size-and-set-the-header-and-footer-on-print